# Uncaught reflect-metadata shim is required when using ES6 with Angular2 rc3

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6, systemjs

I just updated Angular from `rc-1` to latest `rc-3`.
The app is using JavaScript **ES6** and SystemJS. When I run the app with browsersync, it works. But if I bundle the app (with systemjs-builder) and then run it, I have this error in the browser console

> Uncaught reflect-metadata shim is required when using class decorators.

The problem comes from a component using `@angular/http` with a basic http call, if I remove `import {Http, HTTP_PROVIDERS} from '@angular/http' ;` it works.

Plus, it does not happen with TypeScript but it does with JS ES5 and ES6. Also it doesn't happen with Webpack.

I looked into the bundled code and it appears that SystemJS goes through `Angular` code before `Reflect` code... only with es6

index.js

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
import 'es6-shim';
import 'zone.js';
import {bootstrap} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {App} from './app.js';
bootstrap(App);
```

app.js

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, HTTP_PROVIDERS} from '@angular/http';
@Component({
  selector: 'App',
  template: '',
  providers: [HTTP_PROVIDERS]
})
export class App {
  constructor(http) {}

  static get parameters() {
    return [[Http]];  
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you use any transpiler to use decorators?

Comment: Yes I use https://github.com/systemjs/plugin-babel

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`reflect-metadata`, `es6-shim` and `zone.js` are supposed to be global libraries. Consequently, you should not import them into one of your modules like you do in index.js.

Try removing the import statements in your index.js and reference them in your index.html like it is explained in the [Angular 2 Quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html#!#index):

```
<script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
```

Comment: However I only added `reflect-metadata` in the index.html because when I add `zone.js` I have `index.js:20389EXCEPTION: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

Comment: I am running jasmine.  I dont't have a index.html file.